# Add filled rows after a condition in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, rows, fill

I essentially want that for every unique id, there are three rows.
Each unique id has to have rows with kind=1, kind=2, kind=3.

Some already have all three but some only have a row with observations for e.g. only kind 1 and two.
I also want to fill the values A and B with "0" (not NA) for the newly added rows.

I am quite new to R, so I don't really know how to start at all.

```
id = c("u_1", "u_1", "b_1", "u_2", "u_2", "u_2")
kind = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3")
A = c(3, 4, 11, 3, 4, 6)
B = c(4, 1, 6, 2, 3, 8)

df <- data.frame(id, kind, A, B)
```

Every variation is possible. A person (id) can have kind 1 and 2 but not 3; they can have only 1, only 2, only 3; they can have only 2 and 3 but not one, etc...

So what I would want this code to look like in the end is the following:

| id | kind | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u_1 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| u_1 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| u_1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| b_1 | 1 | 11 | 6 |
| b_1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| b_1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| u_2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| u_2 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| u_2 | 3 | 6 | 8 |

Thank you so much for taking the time to think about my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `tidyr::complete`:

```r
library(tidyr)

id = c("u_1", "u_1", "b_1", "u_2", "u_2", "u_2")
kind = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3")
A = c(3, 4, 11, 3, 4, 6)
B = c(4, 1, 6, 2, 3, 8)

df <- data.frame(id, kind, A, B)

complete(df, id, kind, fill = list(A = 0, B =0))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   id    kind      A     B
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 b_1   1        11     6
#> 2 b_1   2         0     0
#> 3 b_1   3         0     0
#> 4 u_1   1         3     4
#> 5 u_1   2         4     1
#> 6 u_1   3         0     0
#> 7 u_2   1         3     2
#> 8 u_2   2         4     3
#> 9 u_2   3         6     8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh wow, that's a quick fix! Thank you so much. I seriously thought I'd have to write lines and lines of code for something like this.

Comment: :D That's what I did before I discovered `tidyr::complete`.

Comment: I definetly have to look at more of the packages it seems :) Thanks again. Have a great weekend!